# How To - Use SSL certificate where Web API is running via Windows Services

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core-webapi

Environment:
ASP.NET .Net Core 3.1 Web API
Windows Server 2016

How do I use my SSL certificate for Web API that is running as a Windows Service on Windows Server 2016? (IIS is not installed)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in Powershell (where 1110 is your port, 'Everyone' depends on system's language, replace XXX with certificates thumbprint, and xxx with app id):

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:1110/ user=Everyone
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName 0.0.0.0:1110 -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:1110 certhash=XXX appid={xxx}
```

Afterwards you should be able to run the app with https.

Remember to run it with Administrator privilages.

Comment: I am using a 3rd Party SSL certificate, so would it still be ```New-SelfSignedCertificate```?

Comment: No, then you can just get the thumbprint from the provided certificate. It is in the details of certificate (Windows).